# Number of real roots of $f(x) = (x^6) + 2(x^4) + (x^2) - 2(x) + 1$

Tags: polynomials, roots, irreducible-polynomials

The question is to find the number of real roots of the polynomial -

**$f(x) = (x^6) + 2(x^4) + (x^2) - 2(x) + 1$**

I used the Descartes rule of signs. Using it, it is clear that there are maximum number of 2 positive real roots and no possible negative root. But after that I was stuck.

Then I changed the approach and calculated it's derivative. Using Descartes rule of signs, I determined that it's derivative has maximum of 1 positive real root and no imaginary root. It means graph is non-monotonic. So, I tried to find the minimum value of function by keeping derivative zero. But I stuck yet again.

Comment: Descartes tells you that $f'$ has exactly one positive zero.  And (I assume you mean) no negative zero.

Comment: it is $x^6 + 2 x^4 +(x-1)^2 $  and could only be zero if $x=0,1,$   both of which give positive values for $f(x)$

Comment: [All six roots are complex.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=x%5E6%2B2x%5E4%2Bx%5E2-2x%2B1)

Answer (score 3):

Note
$x^6 \ge 0$ with equality only for $x=0$;
$2x^4 \ge 0$ with equality only for $x=0$;
$x^2-2x+1 = (x-1)^2 \ge 0$ with equality only for $x=1$.
Adding, we conclude $f(x) \ge 0$ with no equality.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but the last three terms we can factor them
\begin{equation*}
x^2-2x+1=(x-1)^2
\end{equation*}
Hence, $f(x)=x^6+2x^4+(x-1)^2\geq 0$. Since each term is quadratic, we have $f(x)=0$ if and only if
\begin{equation*}
x^6=2x^4=(x-1)^2=0
\end{equation*}
The above implies that $0=x=1$ and
therefore, $f(x)$ has no real roots.

Comment: What are you not sure about?